# Hatred of Chinese

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language

Sinophobia specifically describes fear of all things Chinese. Is there a word specifically to describe hatred (not fear) against a particular race? Right now I'm using *anti-Chinese sentiment*, but that is really clunky. Perhaps a new word made from the combination of the prefixes "miso" (indicating hatred) and "sino"? Perhaps *missinogy*? I am writing an essay on Chinese discrimination.

Comment: `Sinophobia` and `anti-Chinese sentiment` are equivalent in meaning I belive.

Comment: As for your paper on anti-Chinese sentiment, I found a book that you might find useful: The real Chinese in America; being an attempt to give the general American public a fuller knowledge and a better understanding of the Chinese people in the United States (1923).  Two chapters are relevant to your research: X. Legal Treatment ..... 117
XI. Social Treatment 127.

Comment: The author,  J. S. TOW  uses the terms " to
arouse racial hatred", "excite racial hatred", "tending to promote racial
hatred", "despise and
hate the Chinese", but his most used terms is 'anti-Chinese',  'Sino' is not used but 'Chino' is as in Chino-American

Comment: "Bret Harte and others were aroused by the unfair treatment of the Orientals and by the prejudice of the Americans. Harte's poem, Plain Language from Truthful James, published in the Overland Monthly in 1870, was reprinted many times. Two illustrated editions appeared shortly and two musical versions of the poem and a Heathen Chinee Songster were published."-Western concepts of China and the Chinese, 1840-1876, ... . Mason, Mary Gertrude, 1900

Comment: BTW, the author, Mary Gertrude Mason mentions American contact with the Chinese was negligible before 1848, and for this reason alone, 'anti-Chinese' sentiment was localized to California.  -perhaps their was a provincial term?  I'm convinced that 'phobia' indicates a 'fear' or 'dislike' and 'hate' is  altogether another matter but the politics of language has bled the understanding

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sinophobia** works.

The suffix **[-phobia](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/-phobia)** means

> Extreme or irrational fear *or dislike* of a specified thing or group:
>   *arachnophobia, 
>   Russophobia*

While the original root of *[phobia](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=phobia&searchmode=none)* is from the Greek *phobos* or fear, as a suffix, it more often means hostility rather than fright, as in *[homophobia](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/homophobia)*

Answer (score 1):

Anti-Sinitic conveys the idea of opposition to Chinese peoples and culture.

Answer (score 0):

**Misogallic**

> (mis-o-gal'ik), a. [Gr. /uaeiv, to hate, + E. Gallic] Disliking the
>   French; hostile to the French. [Rare.] -The Century dictionary and cyclopedia, with a new ... v.6 M-O.

**Miso**- [— see mis * * * a combining form meaning hate, with the object of hatred specified by the following element: misogyny. Also, mis . [ < Gk, comb. form of miseîn to hate, mîsos hatred] * * * miso /mi sō or mī sō / combining form Signifying a hater …](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/245363/miso-)

Comment: Those cheese-eating surrender monkeys!

Comment: Hmm, tu appelle un chat un chat ;-)

Comment: This is the best answer, please vote for it. *Phobia* can be used to mean hatred as well, as the accepted answer says, but *miso-* is more precise.

Comment: @Cerberus I would fully agree if this answer would indeed give an actual answer to the question, instead of a suggestion as to how to get to that answer. This answer does not tell me what hatred of Chinese would be, unless the Chinese are French and/or female.

Comment: @oerkelens: Well, I suppose mentioning *misosiny* should be mentioned explicitly, but surely people will figure it out?

Comment: @Cerberus OP had tired _missinogy_ so I guess the formation is not obvious :)

Comment: The formation is certainly not obvious, because the combining form _Sino-_ does not have a non-combining form on which to base an abstract noun. Try the same with _pseudo-_: someone who hates/fears falsehoods would suffer from _misopseud--_ what? _Misopseudy_? _Misopseudony_? Same with _Sino-_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I'm not sure I understand how anything but *-siny* or *-pseudy* would be possible? It's fairly straightforward. As with other words on *-y*, you simply take the stem and add *-y*. You get the stem from a prefix on *-o-* by removing the o. Sinology → sino- → sin- → misosiny, just like sociology → socio- → soci- → soci-al/soci-ety, or anthropology → anthropo- → anthrop- → misanthropy. Why would you want to add *-on-*? If *sin-* or *pseud-* had been exceptions, which would have been possible, then this should have been mentioned. But they aren't...

Comment: @Cerb, I agree—but the very fact that there are no words with these two as the last element means that making a parallel is something that requires knowing how to extrapolate pseudo-Latin-Greek roots (rather than just using the form found in other words, as with _-ology_), which to most people makes it not obvious at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: It seems either you underestimate the abilities of the average "English expert or enthusiast" or I overestimate them...

Answer (score 0):

"**Bigotry**" (or "**Bigot**") is a generalized term meaning - "hates or refuses to accept the members of a particular group (such as a racial or religious group)".

Or possibly just "**Racism**" (or "**Racist**") - defined as "the belief that some races of people are better than others.